# Using "+=" in array of Counters resulted in an unexpected behavior, Python

Tags: python, operators

I am using Python 3.4.1 and I was wondering about the following situation:

Given an array of counters

```
cnt = [Counter()] * n
```

I want to add some items in a specific position, so I do

```
cnt[i] += Counter(x)
```

For the construction "+=", I was trying to do

```
cnt[i] = cnt[i] + Counter(x)
```

But, instead of what I expected, I received something equivalent to

```
for i in range(0, n):
    cnt[i] = cnt[i] + Counter(x)
```

In other words, it added all my counters in the array.

- Is this behavior (add every item of the array) common in Python?
  Am I interpreting anything wrong?
- There is a correct/easy/safe way to write what I desired?
- Is this a bug of the version?

An short example:

```
from collections import Counter

text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
cnt = [Counter()] * 2

i = 0
for c in text:
    cnt[i] += Counter(c)  # cnt[i] = cnt[i] + Counter(c)
    i = (i+1) % 2

for i in range(0, 2):
    print(cnt[i], i)
```

Output:

```
Counter({' ': 7, 'i': 6, 'e': 5, 't': 5, 'o': 4, 's': 4, 'm': 3, 'r': 3, 'c': 3, 'u': 2, 'p': 2, 'a': 2, 'l': 2, 'd': 2, 'n': 2, '.': 1, 'g': 1, 'L': 1, ',': 1}) 0
Counter({' ': 7, 'i': 6, 'e': 5, 't': 5, 'o': 4, 's': 4, 'm': 3, 'r': 3, 'c': 3, 'u': 2, 'p': 2, 'a': 2, 'l': 2, 'd': 2, 'n': 2, '.': 1, 'g': 1, 'L': 1, ',': 1}) 1
```

Expected output:

```
Counter({'t': 4, 'i': 3, 'r': 3, 's': 2, 'e': 2, 'm': 2, 'c': 2, 'n': 2, 'a': 2, 'l': 2, ',': 1, 'd': 1, ' ': 1, 'L': 1}) 0
Counter({' ': 6, 'o': 4, 'i': 3, 'e': 3, 's': 2, 'u': 2, 'p': 2, '.': 1, 't': 1, 'g': 1, 'd': 1, 'm': 1, 'c': 1}) 1
```

Comment: All the elements of the `cnt` array refer to the same counter. You didn't make a copy of it when you used the `*` operator.

Comment: Are you sure? I already used `*` other times and it works well, ie, make different copies.

Comment: @MFS: No it doesn't. You might have thought it did if you were using immutable objects, but even then, you had multiple references to one object. Immutables just handle things like `+=` differently.

Comment: Specifically, if you have an array of numbers, it works because they're immutable. So it updates the array reference rather than the shared object.

Comment: @MFS I think you have a valid point. I am using 2.7.2 and I get same output for your sample whether I do "cnt = [Counter()] * 2" or "cnt = [Counter() for i in range(2)]"

Comment: @user3885927: That's because support for `__iadd__` was added to Counter in a later Python version. I don't remember which, but 3.4 should have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `cnt = [Counter()] * n`, what you're doing is creating a single counter, then making every element in your list point to that counter. You're *not* creating `n` Counters, you're creating a single one.

This is because in Python, everything is stored by reference (sort of. More info [here](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)). You've essentially duplicated the reference to the counter object `n` times, not the counter itself.

That means that doing `cnt[i] += Counter(x)` will modify the underlying counter, making it appear like the entire list changed.

To fix this, try doing something like the following:

```
cnt = [Counter() for i in range(n)]
```

Now, you're genuinely creating `n` different counters (because you call the constructor `n` times) and will get the expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. But, do you know why when I change the line with the comment (in the example I gave) for the comment, I reach the expected output?

Comment: @MFS: `a += b` isn't equivalent to `a = a + b`. `+=` requests that the object perform the operation by modifying its state, rather than by returning a new object, if it supports modification.